# How to run an easy Battletech campaign

Tags: battletech

My friends and I are wanting to run an simple Battletech campaign where our pilots have a chance to grow and progress after a few scenarios.

Which products from [Catalyst Game Labs](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/2216/Catalyst-Game-Labs) could offer this experience?

An extended look has led us down a rat hole of expectations without an easy answer.  All of their products seem so inter-related without a way for one to dip their toes into a "shallow end" without drinking the kool-aid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest jumping off point is the recent **BattleTech: Beginner Box**, but if you've got more than two potential players the more extensive **BattleTech: A Game of Armored Combat** will cover up to 8.

Once you've wet your toes you can move on to a fuller campaign with the free [Chaos Campaign](https://bg.battletech.com/download/CAT35600_ChaosCampaign_Rulebook.pdf), or any of the *BattleTech: Starterbook* series (*Sword and Dragon* is intended as the first one, but needs it's errata to work).